# problem with java accents through the console

Tags: java

I'm starting with Java and one of the tasks that send the teacher was to make a program and compile it with the console, this program must send a message, everything works fine except that the accented words are not well painted on my console Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this sort of issue with using a non-Unicode font in swing, but never in the console

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include OS, which console you are using, and a [mre] of the program you are executing.